# Adjoining an nth root of unity to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

$\zeta_n$ is the nth root of unity (or $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}).$ 
How to show $\zeta_n^k+(\zeta _n^{-1})^k$ an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta _n+\zeta _n^{-1})$?

$\zeta_n^{-1}=\zeta_n^{n-1}$.

Since $(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1})^k\in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta _n+\zeta _n^{-1})$, $(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1})^k=\sum_{i=0}^k(\zeta_n)^i(\zeta_n ^{-1})^{k-i}=\sum_{i=0}^k(\zeta_n)^{2i-k}$, but how do I show $\zeta_n^k+(\zeta _n^{-1})^k$ is a term linear combination of these sums?

EDITED: For example,
$\zeta^2+\zeta^{-2}=(\zeta + \zeta^{-1})^2-2,$
$\zeta^3+ \zeta^{-3}=(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})^3-3(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})+6$

Comment: If you fully expand the first few $(\zeta + \zeta^{-1})^j$, it should be fairly clear what's going on. Is it understanding what's going on that you need help with? Or is it turning that understanding into a rigorous proof?

Comment: I understand that if given $k$ I can most likely write $\zeta^k + \zeta^{-k}$ as a polynomial in $\zeta + \zeta^{-1},$ but I am not able to show that I can do this for all $k$.

Comment: Your formula for $(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1})^k$ is wrong, you need to involve binomial coefficients.

Comment: @ Michael I forgot, but my latter calculations (edited) were done by hand not by the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Induction on $k$.

It's a relatively uncomplicated induction.

Comment: How are you using the inductive hypothesis? If it is true that there are constants $c_i$ s.t. $\zeta ^k +\zeta^{-k}=c_0+ c_1\sum +\cdots +c_k \sum$, I don't see what we can include about $\zeta ^{k+1}+\zeta^{-k-1}$

Comment: Multiply $\zeta^k+\zeta^{-k}$ by $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$.

Comment: You need to prove that if you know it is true for $k$ and $k-1$, you know it for $k+1$. So you need to prove it for $k=0,1$ first.

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea from palindromic polynomials. Easy to show that $x^n+x^{-n}$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $x^1+x^{-1}$.

Comment: I can do it for a given $n$, but I don't see how induction works here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

Note that $\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1}$ is a real number (why?). Also, you have that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1})]=2$ (why?). But, since $\mathbb{R}\cap \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is another subextension of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}$ with $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)\cap \mathbb{R}]=2$ (why?) this implies from what we've said that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1})=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)\cap\mathbb{R}$.

Now, to prove that $\zeta_n^k+\zeta_n^{-k}\in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{-1})$, the above shows it suffices to prove it's real. But,

$$\overline{\zeta_n^k+\zeta_n^{-k}}=\overline{\zeta_n}^k+\overline{\zeta_n}^{-k}=(\zeta_n^{-1})^k+(\zeta_n^{-1})^{-k}=\zeta_n^k+\zeta_n^{-k}$$

Comment: Could you explain why $[\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n:\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n+\xi_n^{-1}]=2$?